# Jupyter open files as tabs using in-built terminal prompt

Tags: terminal, navigation, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I want to navigate using the terminal inside jupyter-lab to open up different notebooks from different locations. At the moment using `$jupyter-lab file.ipynb` opens up a new port in a different window, is there a way to open this within the current port?

Or even how to navigate through the terminal to a file location and then open the UI file manager in that location?

(side note) If vsCode or a different ide provides better functionality please mention as well.

Comment: There is a pull request for implementation of `jupyter open` to do so: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/9687. It might be worth asking on GitHub if there is any update or anything blocking it from being merged.

Comment: Thanks, I will post a comment, it would be cool as you can already do it all through the UI, but I guess at the moment the terminal is just a straight redirects straight to the OS terminal?